# Getting an error when run my own rpc node on custom EC2 instance

Tags: rpc, validator

I'm currently working on setting up my own RPC node for the Solana blockchain. I found a script from the Solana documentation that I've used to launch the node. However, I encountered a problem where the process got killed after running for some time.

Here's the script I used:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
set -e 
exec solana-validator \
    --no-voting \
    --identity ~/validator-keypair.json \
    --known-validator 7Np41oeYqPefeNQEHSv1UDhYrehxin3NStELsSKCT4K2 \
    --known-validator GdnSyH3YtwcxFvQrVVJMm1JhTS4QVX7MFsX56uJLUfiZ \
    --known-validator DE1bawNcRJB9rVm3buyMVfr8mBEoyyu73NBovf2oXJsJ \
    --known-validator CakcnaRDHka2gXyfbEd2d3xsvkJkqsLw2akB3zsN1D2S \
    --known-validator RBFiUqjYuy4mupzZaU96ctXJBy23sRBRsL3KivDAsFM \
    --only-known-rpc \
    --ledger /mnt/ledger \
    --accounts /mnt/accounts \
    --private-rpc \
    --rpc-port 8899 \
    --rpc-bind-address 0.0.0.0 \
    --dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint4.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint5.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d \
    --wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record \
    --limit-ledger-size \
    --no-port-check \
    --enable-rpc-transaction-history \
    --full-rpc-api \
    --log /data/solana-spare/logs/solana-validator.log
```

I've included the --no-voting argument to set up an RPC node without voting capabilities. Despite this, the process gets killed unexpectedly. Could anyone please guide me on what I might be doing wrong?

Error:
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Running on aws EC2 Instance is in no way recommended; It's expensive and all around there are better options. Personally, I use Latitude for my rpcs.

Regarding your error, it's likely due to OOM killer (out of memory). To solve this, you can move to a server more memory. Refer to the official [validator requirements](https://docs.solanalabs.com/operations/requirements)

Comment: Yes, I'm using https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/run-solana-nodes-on-aws/ This Aws setting to run the Solana RPC node. it almost has "r6a.8xlarge" (Memory: 256 GiB) But the process was still killed after some time. Also, I have downloaded snapshots then how can I run my node from that particular node? so some downloading processes will not restart and save time.

Comment: Can you check syslogs for OOM Killer errors?. The AWS guide, also seems a little outdated - I'd suggest you follow the official docs, or something more recent.

`grep -i "oom" /var/log/syslog`